# Delete an expired Certificate from the Azure Portal using Microsoft graph

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azureportal

I am trying to using the Microsoft graph cmdlets to remove expired certificates from an app registration in the azure portal.

I have tried using `Remove-MgApplicationKey` to no avail. I get an error

```
Remove-MgApplicationKey : Unexpected invalid input parameters. At line:73 char:17 + ... Remove-MgApplicationKey -ApplicationId $testapp.Id -KeyId ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The documents for this cmdlets are not very useful at all so I was wondering if anyone had any success in getting this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Note that,[`Remove-MgApplicationKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.applications/remove-mgapplicationkey?view=graph-powershell-1.0) expects **proof** parameter as part of request validation before performing the action. But for expired certificates, you cannot generate proof of possession. Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-rollkey-prooftoken?tabs=csharp#:%7E:text=exceed%2010%20minutes.-,Note,-%3A%20Applications%20that).

Alternatively, you can make use of **[Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)** operation by including only valid certificates details in `keyCredentials` parameter:

I have one Azure AD application named `CertApp` with both **valid** and **expired** certificates in it as below:

[image]

In my case, I used below python code to generate **access token** initially with **`Application.ReadWrite.All`** permission:

```py
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

clientID = "appId"
clientSecret = "secret"
scopes= ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"] 
tenantID = "tenantId"
authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID

app = ConfidentialClientApplication(clientID,clientSecret,authority=authority)
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)
access_token = result.get("access_token")
print(access_token)
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I ran below python code that calls Microsoft Graph API for updating application with only **valid** certificates by including above token like this:

```py
import requests
from datetime import datetime

access_token = "token"
application_id = "appObjId"

url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{application_id}?$select=keyCredentials"
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}", "Content-Type": "application/json"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    current_time = datetime.now()
    key_credentials = response.json().get("keyCredentials", [])

    valid_certificates = [cred for cred in key_credentials if datetime.strptime(cred.get('endDateTime', ''), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') > current_time]
    expired_certificates = [cred for cred in key_credentials if datetime.strptime(cred.get('endDateTime', ''), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') <= current_time]

    print("Valid Certificates:")
    for cert in valid_certificates:
        print(f"DisplayName: {cert['displayName']}, End Date: {cert.get('endDateTime', 'N/A')}")

    print("\nExpired Certificates:")
    for cert in expired_certificates:
        print(f"DisplayName: {cert['displayName']}, End Date: {cert.get('endDateTime', 'N/A')}")

    valid_certificates_payload = [{
        "customKeyIdentifier": cert['customKeyIdentifier'],
        "type": cert['type'],
        "usage": cert['usage'],
        "key": cert['key'],
        "displayName": cert['displayName']
    } for cert in valid_certificates]

    patch_payload = {"keyCredentials": valid_certificates_payload}
    patch_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{application_id}"
    patch_headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}", "Content-Type": "application/json"}

    patch_response = requests.patch(patch_url, json=patch_payload, headers=patch_headers)

    if patch_response.status_code == 204:
        print("\nPATCH request successful")
    else:
        print(f"Error: {patch_response.status_code} - {patch_response.text}")
else:
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, expired certificates **deleted** successfully and only **valid** certificates present in application as below:

[image]